# How do I find out if my html document is well formed in ruby

Tags: xml, ruby

Every html document is an xml document. In the current project there are a lot of html tags which are not properly closed. This is a ruby on rails application. I want to put an after filter which will parse the whole html output and will raise an error if the parsing detects that it is not a well-formed document.

In this case well-formed means that all the tags are properly closed. What is a good ruby parser to use in this case which is also fast.

Comment: Are you generating these HTML documents yourself? Because in the real world, every HTML is *definitely not* a valid XML document. Very, very few are.

Comment: Yes I am generating them. But in my views very often I forget to close a tag. I would like the view to raise error saying that it is not a well-formed xml if I forget a closing tag.

Answer (score 2):

HTMLTidy seems to be the most popular plugin for other languages, and there is a RoR version available too.

http://blog.cosinux.org/pages/rails-tidy

Answer (score 0):

[markup_validity](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/06/12/easy-markup-validation/) provides some (X)HTML validation features.
You can also use nokogiri [as described here](http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk/browse_frm/thread/31145249155a90e9/ac645b6df4ed65c5?lnk=gst&q=well+formed#ac645b6df4ed65c5).

Answer (score -1):

Why would you close your tags?  It's only going to slow you down!

http://blog.errorhelp.com/2009/06/27/the-highest-traffic-site-in-the-world-doesnt-close-its-html-tags/

Comment: If the page is going to claim to be XHTML then it should try to be valid XHTML. But yeah, if you're already counting on quirks mode, who cares.